generating pdf using jspdf in html giving blank space in document
I am trying to generate pdf using html and jspdf, my live link is,
Link
Here bottom you can see download button to download the html as pdf, the download is working fine, but there are white spaces in each page on all sides, is there anyway to get rid of it, making the html fit to pdf,
My js code is,
document.getElementById('download-pdf').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#section-to-print .page');

    const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');
    const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    const pdfHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

    elements.forEach((element, index) => {
        html2canvas(element, {
            scale: 1.5, // Lowered scale to reduce file size while maintaining good resolution
            useCORS: true // Only use if you have external resources like images
        }).then((canvas) => {
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7); // Use JPEG format and set quality to 70%
            const imgWidth = pdfWidth;
            const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;

            // Adjust image height if it exceeds the PDF height
            const adjustedHeight = Math.min(imgHeight, pdfHeight);
            const yOffset = (pdfHeight - adjustedHeight) / 2; // Center vertically

            if (index > 0) {
                pdf.addPage();
            }

            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, yOffset, imgWidth, adjustedHeight);

            // Save the PDF when the last page is added
            if (index === elements.length - 1) {
                pdf.save('Custom.pdf');
            }
        });
    });
});

